# Bash Script: How to set a variable as the current time, in the format XX:XX:XX

Tags: macos, mac, osx-yosemite

For a script I'm making, I need to be able to set a variable as the current system time. For example, 11:40:55. This is so the computer sleeps at the exact time, so if there's an easier way to do this, that would be even better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with the following command:

```
TIME=$(date +"%H:%M:%S")
```